# Accessing unique closure on List of objects gives UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I am working on Grails 2.3.11 and am using MongoDb plugin mongodb:3.0.3.

My code looks like this:

```
def home() {
   List abcs = ABC.list()
   println abcs.unique { it.parent }
}
```

The code breaks while accessing unique closure.

The exception says:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver- UnsupportedOperationException   occurred when processing request: [GET] /MongoAppInEcomEnv/product/home
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
Line | Method
->>  148 | add       in java.util.AbstractList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    108 | add       in     ''
|    342 | addAll .  in java.util.AbstractCollection
|    120 | $tt__home in com.test.aitm.ProductController$$EPCH6LtA
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: can you please relate the line 120 to your code there.  does the list there contain null objects? e.g. could simply `it.parent` be failing because of that `it` beeing `null`?

Comment: Hi @cfrick, I have checked it, its not null in the Collection. Infact null can't exit since parent field is nullable:false.

Comment: please show us the code line 120 if the ProductController

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the list is empty.

Also you could try

```
abcs.parent.unique()
```